# php merge_array says JSON data is not array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Having an issue here. When I attempt to do this:

```
foreach ($validation_fields as $val) {
        $rule = json_decode($val['rules'], true);
        $key = 'fields[' . $val['group_id'] . '][' . $val['field_id'] . ']';
        if (array_key_exists($key, $rules)) {
        array_merge($rules[$key], $rule);
        }
    }
```

PHP throws an error back at me saying that argument 2 is not an array, however, when I dump $rule or use is_array($rule), it checks out as being an array. I am so confused.

the json I am decoding is:

```
'{"format": {"rule": ["matches","/[0-9]{9}/"], "negate": true,"message": "Apps"}}'
```

var_dump(json_decode($rule)) is:

```
array
  'format' => 
    array
      'rule' => 
        array
          0 => string 'matches' (length=7)
          1 => string '/[0-9]{9}/' (length=10)
      'negate' => boolean true
      'message' => string 'Apps' (length=30)
```

> array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array on line **197** in ....

Comment: Can you post the PHP error verbatim.

Comment: posted, removed the junk though.

Comment: What is `$validation_fields`?

Comment: a result of a query to the db returned as an array.

Comment: Since this is a `foreach`, is it possible that one of the loops has the array off? Can you confirm via an echo or something which iteration of the `foreach` is throwing the error? The first? second?...

Comment: I found it, buried deep in one of the json strings, someone erroneously placed a "." that I didnt catch until I manually did a validation on each json string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95074/discussion-between-vikingblooded-and-chris).